# Good practice for method chaining in Python?

Tags: python, class, method-chaining

I have written this code in Python which is just for learning purposes.

```
class my_list:

    def __init__(self, lst):    
        self.lst = lst

    def from_(self, n):
        temp_lst =  list(filter(lambda x: x > n, self.lst))
        return my_list(temp_lst)

    def until_(self, n):
        temp_lst =  list(filter(lambda x: x < n, self.lst))
        return my_list(temp_lst)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lst)

x = my_list([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000])

print(x.from_(5).until_(1001)) # [10, 100, 1000]
print(x) # [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
```

My problem is on the returning value of the functions

```
from_
```

and

```
until_
```

I am unable to figure out a way instead of returning a new my_list 'object', to return self and also achieve the same functionality. Is there a way to keep the changes in a temporary class variable and not having to create a class object from scratch ?

So my goal is to do something like this

```
def from_(self, n):
    ### ???
    return self

def until_(self, n):
    ### ???
    return self
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to update `self.lst`.

Comment: But this is my problem. I want ```self.lst``` unchanged.

Comment: I can offer you this alternative if that meets your constraints: https://repl.it/repls/HoarseMobileDefragment otherwise, I don't think its possible, since theres no way to tell (by calling `__str__`) if you want to print the full list, or the partial (filtered) list.

Comment: You may take a look at how the pandas package takes care of this. Most operations in pandas returns a new object, but many of them have the option to operate in place.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you very much. It seems that I should use two classes and keep things separate if I need a certain functionality.

Comment: @user1558604 I will. Thank you.

Comment: @entropyfeverone No problem. All-in-all I would stick with the implementation you currently already have, since that is the most flexible. If you would have `intermediate = x.from_(5)`, you can always specify `foo = intermediate.until_(1000)` and `bar = intermediate.until_(10000)`, while keeping `x` and `intermediate` intact.

Comment: You can **mutate** `self.lst` (in place), **assign** it (thus leaving unchanged any *other* `my_list` objects that somehow share it), or create an entirely new `my_list`.  Nothing else is logically possible.